# JavaFx. Отлавливать unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, javafx, исключения

Интересует способ отлавливать исключения, когда приложением пользуется клиент.

Имеется ввиду, что когда приложение используется и возникает `unchecked` исключение, всплывает `alert` который предлагает отправить инфу разработчику, а в самом `alert` выводит описание исключения.

Подозреваю, что можно сделать какой-нибудь `listener` и с его помощью реализовать данный функционал, однако реализация мне не ясна.

Comment: Вроде бы должен работать [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут нужен [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler()     {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            log.error("Runtime error", e);
            Notifications.create()
                    .title("Произошла ошибка")
                    .text("Подробности в log-файле.")
                    .showError();
        }

    });
    launch(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`unchecked` исключения могут быть пойманный в блоке `try catch` и соответственно обработаны.

```
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("unchecked");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Единственная загвоздка которая может вам встретится это попытка произвести манипуляции с объектами вашего FX приложения не из главного потока приложения(чревато исключением)Для этого в FX предусмотрен статический метод

```
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
```

из данного метода Вы и вызываете окно взаимодействия с пользователем ну а далее событийно-ориентированная парадигма в помощь

UPD: ах так вот в чем проблема... Проверка является ли исключение `unchecked` ?Тут насколько я помню все просто: все непроверяемые исключения  происходят от двух родителей Error и RuntimeException т.ч обычная проверка:

```
    try {
        throw new IOException();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof RuntimeException || e instanceof Error) {
            System.out.println("unchecked " + e);
        } else {
            System.out.println("checked " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

проведет должную отбраковку...

Comment: В том то и дело, что у меня нет возможности обработать все потенциальные unchecked exceptions. Поэтому я хочу, чтобы можно было видеть неожиданно возникшие исключения. Например, если запускаешь приложения через IDE, стэк таких исключений появляется в System.err. Т.е. по сути иметь возможность получать инфу из System.err